# What would I need to set up a local test service/server?

Tags: sharepoint-server, project-server, visual-studio-2013, testing

We would like to set up a locally hosted test server that we could develop some custom workflows and code with to eventually push up to the customer's server. What would be the best software and set up to get this done? We'd like to use Visual Studio 2013 to build the workflows.

Comment: SP2010 or SP2013? Do you have virtual hosts or physical servers?

Comment: SP2013, virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Their are many different ways to build a Dev Farm for development. You can use Window Azure to configure the SharePoint 2013 dev environment.If you have an MSDN subscription, then you can quickly setup your farm.Start: [Set up the development environment for SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869(v=office.15).aspx)

Another Way, if you have server hardware then you need, windows OS(2008 or above), SharePoint Server 2013, SQL Server & DC.

Or you can use the Hype-V and build it.[Setting Up an Awesome SharePoint 2013 Dev Box on Windows Server 2012 R2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sambetts/archive/2014/02/27/setting-up-an-awesome-sharepoint-2013-dev-box-on-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx)